# Android Studio saving .txt/.doc file in Downloads folder

Tags: android-studio, fileoutputstream

I am writing a code in Android Studio and I want to save the user input .txt/.doc file in a folder that I have created in Downloads folder(MyFolder), but I cannot manage to do that.
I have all the permissions to the External Storage. I know that I have to use FileOutputStream instead of openFileOutput, but I do not know how.

This is my piece of code:

```
String text1 = "Name: " + name.getText().toString();
String FILE_NAME = "The name is: " + name.getText().toString() + ".doc";
FileOutputStream fos = null;
File makedir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/MyFolder");
    makedir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(makedir, FILE_NAME);

    try {

        fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(text1.getBytes());
        fos.write("\n".getBytes());
        
        name.getText().clear();

        Toast.makeText(this, "File Saved!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```